# database query via django orm in template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-orm

```
<ul>
    {% for staff in staff_list %}
        <li>{{ staff|title }}<br>
        {% for person in movie.staff.all %}
            {{ person }}<br>
            <a href="{% url 'person_page' person.slug %}"><img src="{{ person.photo.url }}"></a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I iterate over the list "staff_list" and want to take from the model "movie" the field that is in the variable "staff", but orm django calls the field "staff", but I do not have such a field, and therefore nothing is returned. How to call the data that is in the "staff" variable and not call the "staff" field

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be to build the template dataset in view and then loop it in template.

Datalogic should be happening in view and template should focus on rendering.

A dictionary with person and related movies should be build in view.